# UICollectionViewCell subviews not being updated on unit test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uicollectionviewcell, kiwi

I have a test where I want to load a UICollectionViewCell (`CustomCollectionViewCell`), pass some data to it and check if the labels of the cell are updated with this data.

`cell.nameLabel` is a UILabel of the cell and the method `setText` is called but the text itself is never updated.

`cell.nameLabel.text` returns always the initial text defined in the xib.

The label is defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
```

And the spec:

```
SPEC_BEGIN(CustomCollectionViewCellSpec)

describe(@"CustomCollectionViewCell", ^{

    __block CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = nil;
    __block CustomCollectionViewCellData *cellData = nil;

    beforeEach(^{

        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCollectionViewCell"
                                                         owner:self
                                                       options:nil];

        for (id object in objects) {

            if ([object isKindOfClass:[CustomCollectionViewCell class]]) {

                cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *)object;

                break;
            }
        }

        cellData = [[CustomCollectionViewCellData alloc] init];
        cellData.name = @"Custom name";
    });

    afterEach(^{

        cell = nil;
        cellData = nil;
    });

    it(@"should populate the views with the cell data", ^{

        [[cell.nameLabel should] receive:@selector(setText:)
                           withArguments:cellData.name];

        [cell configureWithCellData:cellData];

        [[cell.cellData should] equal:cellData];

        [[cell.nameLabel.text should] equal:cellData.name];
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how are you creating the cell.
You can't alloc init a cell or get the nib. You ask a collection for it.

For collections you need:

```
    UICollectionView *collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] init];
    UICollectionCell *cell = [collection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"yourCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:0];
```

After this, you will be able to get your cell and modify it without having all it's properties as nil properties.